# Excel: Can't remove add-in ribbon

Tags: excel, ribbon

I was playing around with adding some custom buttons in VBA. The problem is that I've somehow created a menu in a ribbon that I can't remove. There a no add-ins enabled, but every time I open a new document (without any code) the add-in menu is there. Does anyone know how to remove it?

I know how to create and delete menus and buttons with commands like:

```
 Application.CommandBars("Formatting").Controls("TEST").Delete
```

But the problems is there there are no controls in this menu and I can't know what the command bar is named, I've already with with "Menu Commands" and multiple generic delete all code that I found on google, without luck.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying for a while, I was able to find a solution myself. It turns it was not just a menu that I had created, but a button without a caption. I was able to remove it by right-clicking the "button", pressing "Delete Custom Command", and then restart (if you don't restart, it will just show up again).

[image]